# Jiray REST API - Querying for issues with all of the fields in a flat JSON structure

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api

In the backlog view of a project, I can select one or more issues and export them to Excel. Here's what I see when I open it.

[image: Manual Excel Export]

Each issue takes up a row. Each field in an issue takes up a column in excel.

If I were to visualize this in JSON it would look something like

```
[

issue1:{
        field1:value1,
        field2:value2,
..
  },
issue2:{
}
]
```

So the issue block has all of the attributes in a flat structure.

Is there a URL mapping in the JIRA api that can get me a response in a flat structure as above? Most of their documented apis return data in nested structures (there are different levels of complex objects for "Issues").

Answer (score 0):

The REST API search and issue resources will let you extract the information. You can then normalize it into the flat json you want. Note that some fields such as components ca contain multiple values